# Использовать в поле типа foreignkey со связью модели с самой собой, кастомный менеджер модели

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

Попробовал несколько вариантов, но ни один не подошел (через формы, через limit_choices_to). Может кто-то сталкивался или есть какие-то идеи или совет или лучшая практика к подобной задаче?
За ранее благодарен!

**Вопрос:** как в модели в поле со связью foreignkey сама на себя и аналогично в поле m2m сама на себя можно использовать не кастомный менеджер модели по умолчанию, а другой кастомный менеджер?

**Суть вопроса подробнее:**

Есть потребность: отдавать в 95% логики проекта отфильтрованные новым, определенным способом инстансы пользователей (для этого переопределен менеджер по умолчанию) - это важная деталь вопроса (вариант - применить во всех вью проекта новые условия фильтрации не подойдет к сожалению).

При этом, в данной модели есть поля со  связью сама на себя foreignkey и еще сама на себя m2m и в них нужно иметь возможность выбрать инстансы пользователей не только те, которые туда отдает менеджер по умолчанию, но и те, что он отбрасывает своим фильтром.

**Пример кода:**

```
class NotDeletedNotRecommenders(models.Manager[Model]):

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Any]:
        return super().get_queryset().filter(deleted__isnull=True, is_recommender=False)


class User(models.Model):
    """
    Пользователь.
    """

    is_recommender=models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        verbose_name="Рекомендующий пользователь"
    )
    recommender = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", <====Тут не будет инстансов с is_recommender=True А они нужны!!!
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="recommender_user",
        verbose_name="Рекомендующий",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    recommended_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", <====Тут будут инстансы с is_recommender=False так и нужно.
        related_name="users_recommended",
        verbose_name="Рекомендованные пользователи",
        blank=True
    )

    objects = NotDeletedNotRecommenders() <====Тут менеджер удаляет с is_recommender=True - это нужно для выдачи в большинстве случаев.
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

**Логика того, что вообще требуется:**

Есть сущность пользователя.
Пользователи бывают двух видов: обычный и пользователь-рекомендующий (рекомендующий имеет свой список с теми пользователями, которых он рекомендует своему обычному пользователю).

- У обычного пользователя есть только один рекомендующий (o2m), у рекомендующего связь со списком обычных пользователей подлежащих рекомендации (м2м).
  Т.е. "Я - обычный пользователь, мой рекомендующий пользователь рекомендует мне этих обычных пользователей".

Также предусмотрен софт-делит (условно удаленный пользователь - тот у которого поле deleted=True)

**ВАЖНО:**
Во всем проекте не должны по умолчанию нигде учитываться / выдаваться условно удаленные пользователи и пользователи-рекомендующие. - Решено переопределением менеджера модели пользователя по умолчанию (пользователи фильтруются по данным полям).

В итоге, из-за этих связей "сама на себя" невозможно, к примеру, назначить обычному пользователю пользователя рекомендующего ему других пользователей, т.к. используется менеджер по умолчанию, в котором условие "отбросить рекомендующих пользователей".

Может это изначально не лучшая идея или все-таки ее можно реализовать подобным образом?

Спасибо!